# AFNetworking- post request- add simple text to body

Tags: ios, http-post, afnetworking

How do i add a simple string (no JSON or any other format), to a post request using AFNetworking? 
The best i've already succeeded was concat with '='.

And this:

```
 NSURLRequest* request =[myServer multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"http://my.server.com" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    NSData *tmp_data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"my_string!"];
    [formData appendPartWithHeaders:nil body:tmp_data];
}];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `NSData *tmp_data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"myString!"];` - ***???*** The format string is superfluous, the return type is incorrect...

Comment: Thanks! How it should be?

Comment: `NSData *data = [@"my_string" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: Thanks, but the body still doesn't contain "my_string!" plz HELP!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As simple as is, This should be the answer:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.my.server.com"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//set headers
NSString *contentType = @"text/xml";
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"any-value" forHTTPHeaderField: @"User-Agent"];

//create the body
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
[postBody appendData:[@"my_body_string!" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//post  
[request setHTTPBody:postBody];
```

From here, do what you want with the http `request` (i used with AFNetworking for sending).

Cheers!